# Policy on +1 comments

Tags: discussion, voting, comments

What is the policy on "+1" in comments? Should they be flagged?

I think that "+1" should not be included in any comment because +1 is what you do with an upvote. It is meaningful to state what you think of an answer but to also include "+1" is not meaningful. Every post would be cluttered with "+1" comments if everyone stated how they voted and that is partly what the voting function is for.

Comment: They are not that often used here to be annoying, aren't they? Adding +1 to a comment below an answer shows that *you* up-voted the question, mostly followed by the reason why the answer was thought to be so good that a comment had been added. Also I like to add +1 if I point out an error in it but want to show that I like the answer anyway and up-voted it.

Comment: Once one has done an upvote/downvote for a question/answer, that belongs to others, +1/-1 should be automatically added by the server script whenever she/he makes a comment or subsequent comments. This way can also prevent bad people from making a lie.  It is just a suggestion.

Comment: @xport people shouldn't feel watched and framed for their opinions or assessment -- the same reason you use the handle "xport" instead of your real name. Besides, this avoids a lot of social friction: "why did you -1 my answer to this question when I have +1'ed you a few times before?!". SE network definitely doesn't need this kind of interaction, hence the anonymity of voting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not the +1 that is (potentially) problematic, but the *content* of the comment. Comments should constructively add to the post in some way, so

> +1 awesome post dude you rock!

.. doesn't, whereas

> +1 but I have also noticed that when  you frimboz the frazbot, sometimes the minmoz alignment can get out of sync.

.. does.

In other words it can be OK to have the +1 in a comment, so long as the rest of the comment is meaningfully constructive and not a mindless "thumbs up".

Comment: As long as we don't get the youtube style "thumbs up if you agree" comments, I'm happy. =)

Comment: +1 for answering. ;-)

Comment: plus one for answering too.